# Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two sets. How many different one-to-one functions are there? How many functions are not one-to-one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two sets where $|X| = 7$ and $|Y| = 10$. How many different

(a) one-to-one functions are there from $X$ to $Y$?

(b) functions are there from $X$ to $Y$ which are not one to one?

(c) one-to-one functions are there from $Y$ to $X$?

(d) functions are there from $Y$ to $X$ which are not one to one?

I was faced with this question, and I have no idea how to solve it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least for (c) and (d), try to write down explicit functions, and see how many different one-one functions you are able to construct.

Answer (score 1):

For a)...

imagine the sets are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ for $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then $f(1)$ can be any number from $1$ to $10$, but $f(2)$ can only be one of the nine numbers from $1$ to $10$, because $f$ is one-to-one and $f(1)$ is already 'taken'. Similarly, $f(3)$ can only be eight numbers.

In light of this, you might be able to see the number of functions (for question a) has the form of $$\frac{a!}{b!}$$

What are $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0):

Functions from $X$ to $Y$ are $Y^X$ and their number is $|Y^X|$, i.e. $10^7$. From this you can extract how many are not one-to-one.

Could there be any one-to-one functions, from $Y$ to $X$, in light $|X|$ should be then greater-or-equal to $|Y|$?

Yet for all functions it is now $X^Y$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a combinatorics Problem
So Let |X| = m and |Y| = n

For a function to be One-One every element of domain must match to unique element in co-domain so from Y we want combination of m element to match and then to permute the as below
$${n \choose m}*m!$$

For Function not One-One (Assuming nothing about surjection)
We have we this as a multi set problem for choosing m elements with repetition

$${n+m-1 \choose m} - {n \choose m}*m!$$

also for function to be one-one |Y| >= |X|

Comment: The number of functions from a set with $m$ elements to a set with $n$ elements is $n^m$ since there are $n$ choices in the codomain for each of the $m$ elements in the domain.  Therefore, your answer for functions that are not injective (one-to-one) is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to help you get started.

Denote the number of elements of a finite set $S$ by $|S|$. Then note that for any finite sets $A,B$, the total number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$. This is because there are $|B|$ choices for each of the elements of $A$ to be mapped to.

For a one-to-one function $f:A\to B$, we must have $|B|\ge|A|$. This is because $f(A)\subseteq B$ for all functions $f$, and $|A|=|f(A)|$ if $f$ is injective. Hence if $|B|<|A|$, there can be *no* injective functions from $A$ to $B$.

The number of functions from $A$ to $B$ that are not one-to-one is obviously (total number of functions) $-$ (number of one-to-one functions).

These hints should help you answer your question.